# Setup for IntelliJ proxy dont work (win7)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, proxy, windows-7

I try to setup the proxy configuration on IntelliJ. I follow the help from : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-http-proxy.html

I create an new gradle/Java project. No Dependency from gradle will resolved.

Im working with Win7. There are no fix configurations for proxy setup. The current settings for proxy is:

[Setting for Win7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHjq0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the proxy details in intellij here: 
Preferences -> Appearances and Behaviour -> HTTP Proxy.

Click the "check connection" button there to make sure it is ok, and then refresh Gradle dependancies from the gradle tool window.